# What is an elegant approach to clearing a form when using computed Bindings in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Form bindings can be elegantly set like the below:

```
myVmodelName: {
    get(){
       return this.$store.state.someSate;
    },
    set(val){
       this.$store.dispatch('updateMyState', val)
    }
}
```

These are passed into a standalone module that's purpose is to hold only data about the form:

```
const state = {
    name: '',
    someState1: '',
    someState2: '',
    // etc....
}

const mutations = {
    UPDATE_NAME(state, name){
        state.name = name;
    }
}

const actions = {
    updateName({commit}, name){
      commit('UPDATE_NAME', name)
    }

}

export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions
}
```

This in turn can then be bound to a module in Vuex that will hold all of our forms state. My question is given a form with large amounts of inputs is there an elegant way to essentially clear the state back to it's default without having to write a horrendously long method that just clears the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I don't think that is a good idea to bind using an action.

`action` is by essence an asynchronous task. So the user would not have the proper feedback.

One possibility would be to debounce the set if  this is really what you need. (see lodash _.debounce) Or other possibility is to use `lazy` modifier.

Since you are binding all the get I would suggest to use a modifier to `reset` the state and keep the `reset` logic close to the store.

```
this.$store.commit('reset');
```

And in the store you could do:

```
const initState = { ... }

export default {
    Object.assign({}, initState),
    mutations,
    actions
}

mutations = {
     reset (state) {
         Object.assign(state, initState);
     }
}
```

Comment: I will have to test this first, thanks for the comment on actions I'll do some refactoring.